# How to run Perforce on 64 bit Windows?

Tags: perforce

I am trying to run Perforce on 64 bit Windows Vista for my own use; nobody else will be accessing it. I downloaded all of the components, but I cannot get it to start when I run p4d.exe.

I get:
Perforce server error:

> Listen 1666 failed. TCP listen on 1666 failed. bind: 0.0.0.0:1666:
>   WSAEADDRINUSE

I have tried looking online for help, but, as usual, all of the instructions are over complicated. What am I doing wrong, and how do I get this silly thing to run?

Answer (score 2):

The WSAEADDRINUSE error indicates that another process is already listening for connections on port 1666.

If you used the normal Perforce installer, it installed Perforce as a Windows Service and started it up for you.

That is, the server is already running!

When you use the Perforce installer, you (generally) don't need to run p4d.exe yourself, as the Windows Service arranges that the Perforce server is always running whenever your computer is running.

Just bring up P4V and start working.

Comment: Is P4V the visual interface? I want to use the commandline, but neither the Windows command prompt nor Cygwin are recognizing p4 commands.

Comment: Did you put the directory containing the Perforce executables in your PATH? Start a command prompt and say 'echo %PATH%' and hit return.

Comment: Yes, the installer did that automatically. It is working now. Perhaps it just did not get picked up till I restarted the computer. I know, silly me, that's the first thing that you are supposed to try. Sorry for the trouble.